# Notation using scalar product

Tags: functional-analysis

let $\Omega$ a bounded set of $\mathbf{R}^n,$

$k=\left(k_1,k_2,\ldots\right)$ vector of positive composants andet $h:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbf{R} .$

I want to understand the operation : $\quad \left(k.\nabla\right)h$

Is the expression above mean the product scalare of $ k$ and the gradient of $h$ ?

Are $\left(k.\nabla\right)h$ and $k.\nabla h$ mean the same thing (with or without brackets) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$k\cdot \nabla : \mathcal C^1(\Omega )\to \mathcal C^0(\Omega ),$$ is a differential operator (namely, the derivative in direction of vector $k$) defined by
$$(k\cdot \nabla)h(x):=k\cdot \nabla h(x),$$
for all $h\in \mathcal C^1(\Omega ).$